# Julia conditional assignment based on | (or) in multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, julia, conditional-operator

I have a 3D array, and based on the values in one "row" using the or operator "|", I would like to substitute values in a different row.  I've attempted to build a mwe, here goes:

```
# create new array
Pop = fill(Int8(3), 1, 3, 4)

# change values in one row of array
Pop[:,:,2] = [5,6,7]

# change values in second row of array
Pop[:,:,4] = [9,10,11]


#  attempt conditional substitution, if element-wise value of Pop[:,:,2] equals either 6 or 7,  then substitute the corresponding element wise (across row in dimension 3) for 8
Pop[:,:,2] == 6|7 Pop[:,:,3] .= 8

# to produce this end result
Pop[:,:,3] = [3,8,8]

Pop
```

I'm missing something in the syntax for the substitution.  Thx. J

Answer (score 1):

This works, but requires a temporary variable.

```
julia> temp = Pop[:,:,3]
1×3 Array{Int8,2}:
 3  3  3

julia> temp[(Pop[:,:,2] .== 6) .| (Pop[:,:,2] .== 7)] .= 8
2-element view(::Array{Int8,1}, [2, 3]) with eltype Int8:
 8
 8

julia> Pop[:,:,3] = temp
1×3 Array{Int8,2}:
 3  8  8
```

Comment: Thanks @Nathan Boyer.  This works.  I managed to add more conditions and get that to work as well, will post a solution that works but please let me know if there is a more elegant or simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's clearer to separate the stages:

```
julia> Pop = fill(Int8(3), 1, 3, 4);

julia> Pop[:,:,2] .= [5 6 7];

julia> ind = findall(x -> x==6 || x==7, Pop[:,:,2])
2-element Vector{CartesianIndex{2}}:
 CartesianIndex(1, 2)
 CartesianIndex(1, 3)

julia> Pop[ind, 3] .= 8;

julia> Pop[:, :, 3]
1×3 Matrix{Int8}:
 3  8  8
```

You could also write `ind == findall(in((6,7)), @view Pop[:,:,2])`. You can write `ind_bool = (Pop[:,:,2] .== 6) .| (Pop[:,:,2] .== 7)` but I'm not sure `Pop[ind_bool, 3] .= 8` will work on all versions of Julia.

Another way is just to write an explicit loop. We could loop separately over `for i in axes(Pop,1), j in axes(Pop,2)` but we can also use these multi-dimensional CartesianIndex things again:

```
julia> Pop = fill(Int8(3), 1, 3, 4);

julia> Pop[:,:,2] .= [5 6 7];

julia> for i in CartesianIndices(@view Pop[:,:,2])
         x = Pop[i,2]
         if x==6 | x==7
           Pop[i,3] = 8
         end
       end

julia> Pop[:, :, 3]
1×3 Matrix{Int8}:
 3  3  8
```

Comment: Thanks @mcabbott, very useful.  I'm coming from years of R, is there no way to reduce/shorten by grouping the 6 and 7 being searched for like "(6 |7)" ?.  Appreciate questions are rather trivial but as yet very few examples on net, so will continue to ask.  In Julia are loops slower, like in R?  Thx a bunch.

Comment: Note that `6 |7` already has a meaning, it's a bit-wise or, and there is no special evaluation, so that happens first. I think `x in (6,7)` is the grouping you want, this constructs a tuple (which is free) and then checks whether x is a member, i.e. is equal to some element. Loops are not in general slower, broadcasting is itself just loops. Here, loops also avoid allocating storage for `ind` or `ind_bool`. (There can be caveats like bounds checking & iteration order. And what I wrote is in global scope, but should be in a function if you care about speed.)

Comment: Thanks again, can I push you one further?  What if I have two (or more) conditions to meet, based on two "rows"  such as "if the values in any columns of Pop[:,:,2] == 6 or 7 ... and ... the values in the same columns  of Pop[:,:,4] are >= 10, then substitute the value of 8 into Pop[:,:,3]  ?  I've tried a couple of things but doesn't work so far.  Thx.

Comment: Can you just extract `x = Pop[i,2]; y = Pop[i,4]` and then `if x in (6,7) && y >= 10` in the loop?

Comment: Do I need to "@view Pop[:,:,4]" as well to be able to put "y = Pop[i,4]"  within the loop?

Comment: I've edited the original problem above, slightly to alter Pop[:,:,4].

Comment: For the range of indices, `CartesianIndices(@view Pop[:,:,2]) === CartesianIndices(Pop[:,:,4])  === CartesianIndices(axes(Pop)[1:2])`, where `@view` is just an optimisation, as `Pop[:,:,2]` copies data that we don't need here. All the information is in `axes(Pop[:,:,2]) == (1:1, 1:3)`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to help from @mcabbott and @Nathan Boyer, I've got a solution that works, even managed to add more conditions and it seems to work.  I'll post the mwe solution.

```
# create new array
Pop = fill(Int8(3), 1, 3, 4)
# change some values
Pop[:,:,2] = [5,6,7]
Pop[:,:,4] = [9,10,9]
# what does it look like
Pop

# code to check condition values

# create temp array to be altered if conditions met
temp = Pop[:,:,3]
# see which indexes meet conditions, in this case
# array "Pop[:,:,2]" contains either 6 or 7 ... and ...
# array "Pop[:,:,4]" contains values >= 10
temp[(Pop[:,:,2] .== 6) .|
     (Pop[:,:,2] .== 7) .&
     (Pop[:,:,4] .>= 10)] .= 8
# make changes to original array based on temp
Pop[:,:,3] = temp
# check if it did the job correctly
Pop
```